# Magento Upgrade, getting error with tier prices from 1.4.0.2 to 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

Getting the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`catalog_product_entity_tier_price`, CONSTRAINT `FK_6E08D719F0501DD1D8E6D4EFF2511C85` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_group_id`) REFERENCES `customer_group` (`customer_group_id`) ON DEL)
```

Not sure how to fix this. Any help????

When I check database, customer_group has four rows just like any other magento installation where as catalog_product_entity_tier_price is totally empty.

customer_group table dump:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_group` (
 `customer_group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Customer Group Id',
 `customer_group_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Group Code',
 `tax_class_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Tax Class Id',
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_group_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customer Group' AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `customer_group`
--

INSERT INTO `customer_group` (`customer_group_id`, `customer_group_code`, `tax_class_id`) VALUES
(1, 'General', 3),
(2, 'Wholesale', 3),
(3, 'Retailer', 3),
(4, 'NOT LOGGED IN', 3);
```

catalog_product_entity_tier_price dump:

```
 --
 -- Table structure for table `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`
 --

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (
  `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `all_groups` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Is Applicable To All Customer Groups',
  `customer_group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Customer Group ID',
  `qty` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.0000' COMMENT 'QTY',
  `value` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Value',
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Website ID',
 PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087` (`entity_id`,`all_groups`,`customer_group_id`,`qty`,`website_id`),
 KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TIER_PRICE_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`),
 KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TIER_PRICE_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID` (`customer_group_id`),
 KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TIER_PRICE_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Tier Price Attribute Backend Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`
--
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_6E08D719F0501DD1D8E6D4EFF2511C85` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_group_id`) REFERENCES `customer_group` (`customer_group_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_TIER_PRICE_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_TIER_PRICE_WS_ID_CORE_WS_WS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Please help me how to fix this issue. (using magento 1.7.0.2)

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok., After digging for more than a hour., I found the reason.

In `customer_group table`, `NOT LOGGED IN` group `customer_group_id` must be 0. But in this table, it is 4 which caused this issue.

Upon changing the id to 0, it is now working fine.